# Adding first character of a string to each of the other characters

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, char

I have a string `alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`
I need output like this 

`aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
af
...
ay
az`

how would I add the first character to every one of the other characters and print it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to iterate over the string, that will give you each letter separately:

```py
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for letter in alphabet:
    print("a" + letter)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will always add the first character of any string to all of its characters.

```
for letter in alphabet:
        print(alphabet[0] + letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use built-in method `zip` with `itertool.cycle` :

```
from itertools import cycle
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
list(map(''.join, zip(cycle('a'), alphabet)))
```

**output:**

```
['aa',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'ae',
 'af',
 'ag',
 'ah',
 'ai',
 'aj',
 'ak',
 'al',
 'am',
 'an',
 'ao',
 'ap',
 'aq',
 'ar',
 'as',
 'at',
 'au',
 'av',
 'aw',
 'ax',
 'ay',
 'az']
```